# SFML Game initially slow, yet speeds up permanently when very little is drawn

Tags: performance, sfml

So I have established the base for an SFML game using a tilemap. For the most part, I've optimized it so it can run at a good 60 fps. However, I can only get this 60 fps if at some point the map is halfway off the screen so there is less of it being rendered. This seems like it would make sense, less being drawn means it runs faster, but once the fps increases it stay permanently, even if I then make the entire screen rendering the map with the map. I can't understand this irregularity with the fps in that I either have to start the map slightly offset, or move the map offscreen for a moment to get a solid fps. Clearly there isn't a problem with the ability of my computer to render at this fps, as it can stay there once it starts, but I can't understand why the map has to be offscreen momentarily for it to achieve this speed.

Comment: ...caching, maybe? Does it still run slowly if you never go offscreen?

Comment: How do you expect us to help without some code reproducing this problem? Knowing SFML, I'm sure you can make a minimal version of your problem and show it here. You might even discover the issue while doing it.

Comment: Anyway, you are obviously doing something wrong. Even with the old SFML versions I had hundreds of fps with thousands of objects in the screen. It is certainly something silly going on in your rendering cycles.

Comment: And how do you measure the FPS? As Klaim said, we need code, not just text.